# Failed to load server.component.html

Tags: angular7

This is the main.ts file.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**This is *server.component.ts* file.**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  templateUrl: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent {

}
```

Showing the two errors:

1. GET http://localhost:4200/server.component.html 404 (Not Found)
2. Failed to load server.component.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to show components in angular7.

I think you are lacking the basics of angular

Go through this starter tutorial , to get to learn angular.
https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

In the server.component.ts file just replace the absolute path given in the templateUrl section with the relative path and it will work.

Comment: Tried with both absolute and relative path but did not work...(Angular 8)

Answer (score 0):

As a fast fix for this problem you can just add a dangling comma[two slashes(`//`) after templateUrl] after the templateUrl
as below.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  templateUrl: './server.component.html' //
})
export class ServerComponent {

}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem recently, in my case i search for all componentes that refers to the error and find some errors on angular imports:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '../node_modules/@angular/core';
```

To fix:

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
```